# Osascript & iTU

Tags: python, itunes, osascript

My python code,

```
import subprocess

command = ['osascript', '-e', 'tell application "iTunes" to name of current track as string']
p = subprocess.check_output(command)
```

When i run this i get a FileNotFound error, `FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified`.

I simply want it to return the name of the song that is currently playing, I have entered the full directory like this into it

`command = ['osascript', '-e', 'tell application "C:\Program Files\iTunes\iTunes.exe" to name of current track as string']` however it still does not work.

Any tips or ideas on what might fix this would be very helpful!

Comment: Did you escape the `'\'` characters in the second example?

Comment: no good point, but I have just done that now and it still doesnt work [screenshot](http://prntscr.com/1560los)

Comment: It looks like you are trying to run this in Windows, which doesn't have an `osascript` executable.

Comment: is there a way i can run it?

Comment: If you are asking about running an AppleScript in Windows, the answer is no.